# How to create an a model instance

Tags: python, django

Ok, I have two models here (Room & Message) and the message model is the child of room. so i wanted to add a comment section where a user can comment to other rooms topic.Unfortunately i tried this code below here, and django says;
(Cannot assign "(<Room: MYSQL Triggers>,)": "Message.room" must be a "Room" instance.) I mean i don't understand this. please help me figure this out if you can.

```
        #room model
class Room(models.Model):
 host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
    ordering = ['-updated', '-created']

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name

#message model
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
     
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   
    def __str__(self):
         return self.body
```

#VIEWS TEMPLATE

```
def room(request , pk):
    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk),

    comments = Message.objects.filter(room=pk).order_by('-created')  #get comments
    comments_no = comments.count() #count number of comments
    #create comments

    if request.method == 'POST':
    #The problem seems to be here, but i don't understand how to fix it.
    messaging = Message.objects.create(
        host = request.user,
        room = room,
        body = request.POST.get('body')
    )
    return redirect('room', id=room.id)

    context = {'room': room, 'comments':comments, 'noofcomm':comments_no}

    return render(request, 'base/rooms.html', context)
```

Comment: remove the trailing comma at the `room = ...` line.

Comment: Thank you bro, it really worked, i can't believe an unexpected comma  made me struggle for 8 hrs.

Comment: @allenjade: well personally I consider the trailing comma a bit of a misfeature in Python, it has resulted in a lot more trouble than it is probably worth. Using `(foo, )` makes it clear that you wrap items in a tuple, `foo,` makes it less clear.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes sir Willem you're right this is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the Room object, not the Room pk. Or use Django's ORM Lookup:

```
    comments = Message.objects.filter(room__id=pk).order_by('-created')  #get comments
```

Comment: thanks but now it says;  type object 'Room' has no attribute 'Messages'

Comment: Is there any other piece of code you're calling and not showing here?

Comment: Not really, i only left out the home template, which is only rendering the home template